# Layout convention in matrix derivation

Tags: calculus, matrices

In a book i'm reading there are these formulas, $y$ and $\beta$ are vectors of same dimensions, $X$ is a matrix:

$$RSS(\beta) = (y - X\beta)^T(y - X\beta)$$
$$\frac{\partial RSS(\beta)}{\partial \beta} = -2X^T(y - X\beta)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 RSS(\beta)}{\partial \beta \partial \beta^T} = 2X^TX$$

From what I understand, when he uses $\partial \beta$ as denominator, it uses the numerator layout convention, meaning the derivative is actually calculated w.r.t $\partial \beta^T$, and when $\partial \beta^T$ is used explicitly, it is just the same as using $\partial \beta$ with the numerator layout.

If that is correct, then why is he using two layouts at the same time in the second order derivative, why not just write $\partial \beta^2$, or even $\partial \beta^T\partial \beta$ ?
If using $\partial \beta$ or $\partial \beta^T$ as denominator produces the same result, why not always be explicit and use $\partial \beta^T$ to avoid confusion ?
Is there any advantage to have multiple layouts for matrix derivatives ?

Comment: Note, these equations appear on page 45 of The Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman, 2e. Naming the text may help others find this question.

Answer (score 0):

He's not using two layouts at the same time.  The second derivative is along a different axis, which is why it's written as the derivative with respect to the outer product of Beta.  How would you write the complex Hessian?  With his notation, it is clear how to write it:

$$\frac{\partial^2 RSS(\beta)}{\partial \beta \partial \beta^H}$$